# ¿ Se puede hacer una pregunta de juicio de opinión por expertise ?

Tags: discusión, revisión-de-pregunta

Me gustaría poder recurrir al juicio de opinión de expertos para contrastar ideas y obtener feedback sobre una interrogante relacionada con la arquitectura y estilo de programación para un sdk orientado a developers, pero no estoy seguro si esto corresponde a los lineamientos del sitio.

**La pregunta seria algo como :** *"Se recomienda usar programación idiomática en el desarrollo de un sdk / librería o plugin cuando esta va a ser replicada en varios lenguajes de programación?, o se recomienda tener una arquitectura en común y código similar para todos los lenguajes creando uniformidad, pero en contraparte perdiendo las ventajas de cada lenguaje."*

Comment: puedes ingresar al chat y hacer tu pregunta _de opinion_ ahí, donde sera bien recibida.

Answer (score 4):

Las preguntas cuyas respuestas se encuentran basadas en opinión y las preguntas que propician el debate deben evitarse en el sitio. Ante esas situaciones, lo mejor es utilizar la [sala de chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol). Considera que necesitas por lo menos de 20 de reputación para participar en una sala de chat.

Answer (score 2):

En mi opinión, no.

Obtendrían en ambas preguntas dos posibilidades, "si" y "no". Ambas opiniones podrían estar acompañadas de datos para reforzar esa opinión. El esquema cerrado de SOes es que se requiere de una respuesta correcta y cuando se trata de opiniones o recomendaciones, cualquiera o todas, cuando está la respuesta está bien estructura, con argumentos coherentes, puede ser correcta.

Por otro lado, una pregunta como la que pretendes hacer no debería ser abstracta ni generalizada. La respuesta es *casuística* y depende necesariamente de las necesidades explícitas o implícitas de los desarrolladores o de los usuarios. Aún conociendo esas necesidades, requisitos y todo el entorno, seguiría siendo una opinión.

Answer (score 1):

Casi cualquier tema relacionado con la programación es apropiado si lo enfocas correctamente. Este no es una excepción.

Yo creo que tu mejor alternativa es hacer dos preguntas. Ambas etiquetadas como [revisión-de-código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revisi%c3%b3n-de-c%c3%b3digo).
En una pones código desarrollado con uno de esos estilos, en la otra con el otro estilo.
En ámbas explicas qué quieres conseguir con ese código. Y preguntas cómo mejorar el código desde el punto de vista de mantenibilidad y escalabilidad del mismo. De las respuestas y comentarios que obtengas en ambas preguntas podrás sacar tus conclusiones sobre cual de los dos es el que más te conviene.

Esto además tiene la ventaja de que habrás trabajado con ambos, la experiencia en primera persona resulta muy útil para decidir.
Y tiene un inconveniente. Es más trabajo. Pero el que algo quiere algo le cuesta.