# ¿Puedo usar meta para preguntar detalles sobre mi pregunta antes de publicarla en SOes?

Tags: discusión, revisión-de-pregunta, preguntas

A veces tengo problemas para publicar mi pregunta en el sitio oficial [SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com) porque puede que me equivoque al redactarla, no provea la información suficiente cuando la publique, quizás sea off topic o simplemente hayan usuarios que no les guste mi pregunta. No me gusta que me cierren las preguntas ni que las voten en negativos. Así que quisiera acudir a la misma comunidad para que me ayuden a publicar la pregunta aquí y me la corrijan antes de publicarla en el sitio. ¿Es esto posible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sí, es posible. Es más, **te invito a que lo hagas**.

La plantilla que recomiendo es:

> #### Título: Contexto de la pregunta (el cual se ve grande y en negrita).
>
> ---
>
> Cuerpo de la pregunta: Contenido de tu pregunta, con todo el contenido relevante, incluyendo código y el formato que creas conveniente.
>
> Además, si los lenguajes son *HTML*, *CSS* o *JavaScript* es posible agregar *snippets* para compartir tu código dentro del sitio, y tiene para agregar los frameworks que necesites, como *jQuery*.
>
> Siempre que sea lo más corto posible para poder reproducir el problema, *y no pegando 500 líneas* de código cuando no son necesarias, lo que se conoce como *MCVE (ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable)*.
>
> <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
>
> <!-- language: lang-js -->
>
> ```js
>     console.log( $("div").html() )
> ```
>
> <!-- language: lang-css -->
>
> ```css
>     div{
>         background-color: #D0E0F0;
>     }
> ```
>
> <!-- language: lang-html -->
>
> ```html
>     <script  
>         src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"  
>     ></script>
>
>     <div>¡Hola mundo!</div>
> ```
>
> <!-- end snippet -->
>
> ---
>
> Etiquetas (5 o menos): [etiqueta-1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etiqueta-1) [etiqueta-2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etiqueta-2) [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [html](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) [css](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)

El snippet se ve así:

```js
console.log( $("div").html() )
```

```css
div{
    background-color: #D0E0F0;
}
```

```html
<script  
    src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"  
></script>

<div>¡Hola mundo!</div>
```

Aquí hay un ejemplo que hizo [Joel Ibaceta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/562/joel-ibaceta) hace unos días: [¿ Se puede hacer una pregunta de juicio de opinión por expertise ?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/629/227) (el cual tomé para elaborar esta plantilla).